Multiple Styles of same file showing
I have an HTML JS project using Webpack. I have an old version which is working fine.
I created copy of the project, updated the npm packages and their use to the latest versions. When I run the new project, in styling multiple styles are shown.
I have checked that my project is not calling the styles multiple times.

I have Scss and sassloader and in the Head tag. I can see compiled CSS multiple times

